# Should I Release Object in Primitive C-Array

Tags: ios, memory-management

#### Say you have class Block

```
Class Block : NSObject
```

#### Now, you want to create array in C-style

```
Block *blocks[5]; // or calling malloc()
Block *aBlock = [[Block alloc] init];
blocks[0] = aBlock; 
// at this point, aBlock will be hand over to array blocks slot.
// not like NSArray, object of 'Block' will not retain by @property(retain)
// or should I call retain before hand over the value into its array and release afterward?
// should I still call below code to release object ?
// [aBlock release];
```

#### Can someone explain to me should I still need to release the aBlock object afterward?

Comment: If you did this under arc, you would only have to set the objects in the array to nil when you were done, and not have to worry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because the primitive array won't be retaining each `Block` object. So if you release it, all `Block` objects will be cleaned up the moment the function exits scope